# How to remove outliers from Geo Coordinates before creating a polygon?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm having a set of geo coordinates.

```
LATITUDE    LONGITUDE
43.791442   -79.536768
43.791602   -79.536753
43.790313   -79.539027
43.797055   -79.532563
43.797085   -79.532693
43.800965   -79.53263
43.800927   -79.532787
43.800955   -79.53299
43.800953   -79.532747
43.79723    -79.532805
43.797115   -79.532768
43.79124    -79.54054
43.789708   -79.546182
43.789678   -79.546258
43.789602   -79.54673
43.797172   -79.540958
43.79709    -79.540897
43.800945   -79.532777
43.800858   -79.532997
43.800858   -79.533012
43.800998   -79.532638
43.8002     -79.53382
43.800148   -79.53391
43.798023   -79.549485
43.798162   -79.549513
43.80297    -79.55066
43.802982   -79.550635
43.793313   -79.548608
43.793273   -79.5486
43.79072    -79.54789
43.790505   -79.547832
```

I created a polygon from it using Convex Hull but it resulted in a very big polygon due to several outliers.

I would like to remove those outliers and create a more specific polygon. No other parameters except Latitude and Longitude are there.

I have tried it using the below code for generating the polygon:

```
locations = data_unique[['LONGITUDE','LATITUDE']].copy()
locationlist = locations.values.tolist()
poly_convex = MultiPoint(locationlist).convex_hull
crs = {'init': 'epsg:4326'}
polygon = gpd.GeoDataFrame(index=[0], crs=crs, geometry=[poly_convex])

c = polygon[:]

c['coords'] = c['geometry'].apply(lambda x: x.representative_point().coords[:])
c['coords'] = [coords[0] for coords in c['coords']]

c.plot()
```

Please help me getting the more accurate polygon.
Note: I don't wish to take any predefined distance from centroid as it is in KNN.

Comment: Why not 3-sigma form the mean?

Comment: Or better yet, 3x the covariance ellipse?

Comment: Can you please let me know how to implement it on spatial data? I'm just new to it. :)

Answer (score 2):

For outlier removal, look at this [summary page on sklearn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/outlier_detection.html).

You may also be interested in [alphashapes](https://pypi.org/project/alphashape/) for a better version of a convex hull, which has some amount of built-in outlier removal.